# How to do only simple cross validation using GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

How I am using below code to perform both simple cross validation and K-fold cross validation

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import xgboost as xgb
import numpy as np

# our hyperparameters to choose from
learning_rate = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2]
n_estimators = [30, 50, 100, 150, 200]

param_grid = dict(learning_rate = learning_rate, n_estimators = n_estimators)

xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(random_state=42, n_jobs = -1)

clf = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, param_grid, scoring = 'roc_auc', cv=3, return_train_score=True)

sc = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# getting all the results
scores = clf.cv_results_
# getting train scores and cross validation scores
train_score = scores['mean_train_score']
cv_score = scores['mean_test_score']
```

Comment: What is "simple cross validation"? And what is `X_cv`?

Comment: Simple cross validation mean we train our model on X_train and get results on X_cv(While is data matrix for cross validation only) for difrent set of  parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Access the classifier trained with the best set of hyper-parameters, then call the `score` method, which will make predictions from `X_cv` and score accuracy compared to `y_cv`:

```
clf.best_estimator_.score(X_cv,y_cv)
```

If you just want the predictions, then call the `predict` method instead with `X_cv` as argument.

Comment: But if we pass cv=3 in the GridSearchCV() then it uses 3 fold cross validation which I don't want?

Comment: You have already trained the model with 3-fold CV to select the best set of hyper-parameters. Calling `best_estimator_` won't run 3-fold CV again.